# How to check vor variants of a number with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am runnning a PHP/MySQL webapp where users can post content. Due to spam, I am trying to block uploaders of spam text with the help of keywords.

The spammer will typically enter a whatsapp number which I have on a black list. Recently he placed spaces into the number and therefore my logic is not working anymore.

e.g.:

[image]

My system detects`info` even as a part of `Infos`, but not the number which is defined as a spam keyword, just without spaces.

The relevant line of the following code is:

```
$pos = stripos($data['txt'], $findme);
```

Entire code:

```
# Check for spam keywords
// get the keywords from the black list
$stmt="
    SELECT
        keyword,
        weight
    FROM 
        $DB.$T16
";
$result = execute_stmt($stmt, $link);
while ($row = db_get_row($result)){
    $keyword[]  = $row->keyword;
    $weight[]   = $row->weight;
};  
$num_results = db_numrows($result);
if(!isset($spam['score'])) $spam['score'] = 0;
if(!isset($spam_level)) $spam_level = 0;    
for ($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++){
    $findme  = $keyword[$i];
    $pos = stripos($data['txt'], $findme);
    $pos2 = stripos($data['title'], $findme);
    if ($pos !== false OR $pos2 !== false){ // this seems to be spam!
        $spam_level += $weight[$i];
        $triggered_keywords .= $keyword[$i].', ';
        #echo $spam_level.':'.$keyword[$i].$br;
    }
}
$spam['score'] += $spam_level;
```

That works if the number is as the keyword. E.g. +47179339393. But as the spammer is now entering +47 17 93 39 39 3 and variations of it, it failes.

How could I change the stripos function to make sure that all variant of +47179339393 will be recognized?

Comment: You could simply remove all spaces in the `data['txt']` and `data['title']`. Use `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $data['txt']);`

Comment: First you need to **always** compact and clean it in PHP before storage, and make sure it's always the full international number, then you can search for uniqueness. Just strip-out anything that is not the initial `+` (by checking for it and if necessary restoring) or a number using `preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '',$data['txt']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all variants are defined as having different types/amounts of whitespace, you could just try stripping all whitespace:

```
$number = "+47 17 93 39 39 3";
$number = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $number);
```

To extract your number from the text, try using `preg_match_all`, for example:

```
$input = "Infos auch unter whatsapp nummber:+43 68 86 49 45 702";
preg_match_all("/\+?\d+(?:\s+\d+)*/", $input, $matches);
$number = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $matches[0][0]);
echo $number;

+4368864945702
```

Comment: Not in this casd. I am checking the entire text, not just the number. Updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: It is the case, assuming you can capture the phone numbers using something like `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Interesting approach. How could I alter the regex to capture only numbers > 6 characters in total? That way I would not need to cycle through e.g. year information and such. In the end I want to check against my array of keywords if one of the numbers is within the keyword array.

Comment: What would be wrong with just checking the length of `$number` above?

Comment: You are catching the first number  with $matches[0][0]. If I understand your approach correctly, one would cycle through the $matches array instead as the text contains more numbers and then check against another array of keywords. So I believe reducing the amount of matches to the relevant ones would be helpful.

Comment: @merlin Honestly, you would need a really ugly regex to do what you want.  I prefer my current solution actually.

Comment: Than you for the help. That worked, I went with a slightly adjusted solution. Hope no spammers will come through in the future :-)

Comment: @merlin Have a look at [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JSPg18/1) to see a way to write a pattern which will both target numbers and filter out numbers less than 6 digits.  But, as I mentioned above, the pattern is verbose, and I prefer the answer you already accepted.

Comment: Thank you Tim. The solution is already deployed and works as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_replace_callback()` here with the following expression:

```
\+?\d[\s\d]+\d
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/KkB3Bi/1/).

---

In `PHP` this could be:

```
<?php

$text = <<<END
That works if the number is as the keyword. E.g. +47179339393. But as the spammer is now entering +47 17 93 39 39 3 and variations of it, it failes.

How could I change the stripos function to make sure that all variant of +47179339393 will be recognized?

Infos auch unter whatsapp nummber:+43 68 86 49 45 702
END;

// put the numbers to ignore inside this array
$ignore = [];

// expression from above
$regex = "~\+?\d[\s\d]+\d~";

$text = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($match) {
        $stripped_number = preg_replace("~\s+~", "", $match[0]);
        if (in_array($stripped_number, $ignore)) {
            return "";
        } else {
            // leave it untouched
            return $match[0];
        }
        echo $stripped_number;
    },
    $text);
```

Comment: Thank you Jan. I am not sure if this is a solution to my problem. In the end I want to cycle through my associative array with keywords and weight. E.g. "+493939" -> 20. If the number is a match (found in text) then increase spamlevel: $spam_level += $weight[$i]; Where would I enter this part of the code within your function?